# Cannot activate feature "SharePoint Server Publishing" programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-server

I'm trying to activate "`SharePoint Publishing Server Infrastructure`" and "`SharePoint Server Publishing`" by C# code. Here's my code:

```
SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("http://MySitecollectionUrl");
SPWeb rootweb = siteCollection.RootWeb;
Guid guid1 = new Guid("f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa");
Guid guid2 = new Guid("94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb");
siteCollection.Features.Add(guid1, true);
rootweb.Features.Add(guid2, true);
```

After running the code, I met this error:

> Error Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureDependencyNotActivatedException:
>   Dependency feature 'PublishingSite' (id:
>   f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa) for feature 'PublishingWeb' (id:
>   94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb) is not activated at this scope

But when I check my Sharepoint site, the "Sharepoint Publishing Server Infrastructure" feature was activated by my code.

So, what am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE:
I've tried activating the "`SharePoint Publishing Server Infrastructure`" by code, and then activated the "`SharePoint Server Publishing`" manually, and everything works OK.
This issue really makes me confused. I really don't know why, are there any diffrences between activating feature by code and manually ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("http://MySitecollectionUrl");
SPWeb rootweb = siteCollection.RootWeb;
siteCollection.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
rootweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
Guid guid1 = new Guid("f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa");
Guid guid2 = new Guid("94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb");
siteCollection.Features.Add(guid1, true);
siteCollection.Update();
rootweb.Features.Add(guid2, true);
rootweb.Update();
siteCollection.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
rootweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the following code:

```
SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("http://MySitecollectionUrl"); 
Guid guid1 = new Guid("f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa"); 
Guid guid2 = new Guid("94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb");
siteCollection.Features.Add(guid1, true);

//Get my SiteCollection again
SPSite siteCollection2 = new SPSite("http://MySitecollectionUrl");
SPWeb rootweb = siteCollection2.RootWeb;
rootweb.Features.Add(guid2, true);
```

And it works!!

Still, I don't really understand why I had to get my site collection again ...
It would be great if someone can tell me this.

Thanks :)